# what is the difference between normal OLS simple linear regression and Canonical cointegrating regression?

Tags: macroeconomics

what is the main difference between simple linear regression and Canonical cointegrating regression. Why we should use Canonical cointegrating regression instead of OLS?

Comment: Hi: you use canonical cointegration regression if you want to test that two or more variables are cointegrated. Cointegration is a HUGE topic on its own that had it's official start in 1987 ( engle and granger, econometrica ) so there shouldn't be a problem finding material on it by googling. In your case,  you could google for "johansen and juselius". There will be a lot of material that comes up. But that material is kind of generalization of the 1987 approach so I would start with the EG paper or an econometrics text that explains EG first. It's easier than the JJ material.

Comment: Hello JSM, I actually don't think that your question is well here. Sure, we can use regression in Economics, but it isn't specific to economics. So [Math.SE], [Datascience.SE] or [Stats.SE] would be better places.